# Is parsley lib work on check boxes and also for wizard class of bootstrap. if it is how to prevent it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

In my webapp i have made two `<fieldset>` one for four `<input>` fields and one for
`checkboxes`. Now i am using [this parsely lib](http://parsleyjs.org/) on these `<fieldset>` it is not working on it. but it works on othere pages that in which different fields have been made. now i don't know about this lib so much if it is work on `checkboxes` or not. and also i dont wanna apply parsely lib on these `checkboxes`.
**So my question is :**

- why it does not work on given below code which is in my webapp it is
  one page but on other page it works.?

Here's code:

```
     <form id="form1" action=""  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo empty($user_id)?"":$user_id;?>" />

                   <fieldset>
      <legend>Basic Info</legend>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="name">First Name *</label>
                                                <p id="validation"></p>
                                                <input type="text" class="form- 
     control" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo empty($fname)?"":$fname;?>" 
      placeholder="Enter First Name" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="email">Last Name *</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php echo empty($lname)?"":$lname;?>" placeholder="Enter Last Name" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                      
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="name">Email *</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form- 
    control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo empty($email)?"":$email;? 
     >" 
    placeholder="Enter Email" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="email">Mobile #</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="<?php echo empty($mobile)?"":$mobile;?>" placeholder="+55 99 99999999" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                      
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row" style="display:none;">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="status">Status</label>
                                                <div>
                                                 <span class="text-muted m-l-5">InActive</span>
                                                 <input type="checkbox" data-render="switchery" id="status" name="status" data-theme="default" checked />
                                                 <span class="text-muted m-l-5">Active</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="status">All Permissions</label>
                                                <div>
                                                     <span class="text-muted m-l-5">No</span>
                                                     <input type="checkbox" data-render="switchery" id="status" name="status" data-theme="default" checked />
                                                     <span class="text-muted m-l-5">Yes</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                  

                                        </div>                                  
                                    </div>  


                                </fieldset> 

        <fieldset>
    Here for checkboxes
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. after spending an hour [reading official](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators) docs.It says

> Checkbox, radio and select multiple are a bit different than regular
>   input, textarea or simple select. They need to have either a name or
>   an id attribute to be correctly bound and validated by Parsley.
>   Otherwise, they will be ignored and a warning will be put in the
>   console.